# Advantages on flattening to 1D

Tags: c++

I have questions about the flattening operation I see on forums. People often recommend flattening a multi-dimensional vector, or array to a single dimension one.

For example:

```
int height = 10;
int width = 10;
std::vector<int> grid;
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
        grid.push_back(rand() % i + j);
    }
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> another_grid;
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    std::vector<int> row;
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
        row.push_back(rand() % i + j);
    }
    another_grid.push_back(row);
}
```

I can guess that it's less memory consuming to have a single vector instead of many ones, but what about a multidimensional array of int ? Is there real advantages to flatten multi dimensional data structures ?

Comment: Hard to judge a recommendation without context. Both have their place.

Comment: Unrelated to C++, but Excel VBA scripting gains a TON of performance if you flatten data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of multiple reasons to do this, in no particular order and there might be more that I missed:

1. **Slightly less memory use:** each vector takes 24 bytes*, if you have 1000 rows, it's 24K more memory. Not that important, but it's there.
2. **Fewer allocations:** Again, not very important, but allocations can be slow, and if this is happening for instance in real time and you're allocating buffers for images coming from a camera, having 1 allocation is better than potentially thousands.
3. **Locality:** This is the most important one, with a single allocation, all the data is going to be very close to each other, so accessing nearby data will be much faster either because it's already in the cache, or the prefetching hardware can accurately pull the next cache line.
4. **Easier serialization/deserialization**: For instance, if this is a texture data, it can be passed to a GPU with a single copy. Same applies for writing to a disk or network, though you may want some compression with those.

The downside is it's less comfortable to write and use, but with a proper class abstracting this away, it's pretty much a must-have if performance matters. It may also be less efficient for certain operations. For instance, with the `vector<vector<>>` version, you can swap entire rows with a single pointer swap, and the single `vector` version needs to copy a bunch of data around.

*: This depends on your implementation, but on 64-bit platforms, this is common.